# Did the first operating system programmed in binary? And how did that programmers know what to do?

Tags: binary, operating-system

Did the first operating system programmed in binary?

I'm just curious because It looks like that it should be programmed in binary. But if it's really binary , how would that first programmers know what to write the programs? Isn't he in total blindness?

Also , can you give me the example of command in binary?(First operating system's function if possible).

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, but off-topic here. There are some literature on history of computing, you should read it....!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you state why it's off-topic?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Answer me or I'll assume that you just want to get some helpful flags without look at the real meaning of the question.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't SO about getting help with buggy code? programmers.SE would be more appropriated

Comment: @Theolodis Yeah , do whatever you want with this on-hold questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

The very first computers (like e.g. [Eniac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eniac)) did not have any [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). People programmed them in e.g. binary! Then some guy decided to develop a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_monitor) (which later was called, and evolved in, an operating system).

Even in the 1960s some computers (like the [IBM 1620](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1620)) where able to start without any code (at that time they had no [firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) and no [ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory)): I am old enough to have played, as a teenager, on one (in a museum): you was able, by setting special switches, to type the few machine instructions (in BCD) to load the rest of the system (on punched tapes).

It is a classic [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap) problem. J.Pitrat's blog on [bootstrapping artificial intelligence](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) should have useful references.

Read about [history of computing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware) & [history of operating systems](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24972).

Comment: How about the first operating system? I think I ask about that

Comment: A operating system is really just a glorified program anyway